Mac Plus -- Original Mac Plus Analog Board - Are There Any Problems That Anyone Can See By Looking at the Pictures?
This is my first attempt to diagnose and repair (if necessary, but only if necessary) any apparent defective (or soon likely to become defective or fail) parts on a Mac Plus original analog board.
Right now, the analog board is working (it's powering and providing signal to) a Mac Plus (1988) that I purchased for $200 ($100 plus $100 shipping) that originally had a Sad Mac ROM failure black screen.
I put in new ROMs, upgraded the logic board to 4 MB and the sad Mac turned very happy and booted beautifully. The logic board is in near pristine condition, and other than the defective ROMS which have now been replaced and the board upgraded to 4 MB, everything runs smoothly and without any hiccups.
The screen is perfect, no pixel failures or fade lines or other problems and the only teeny, weeny issue is a barely imperceptible difference in the width between the left black margin and the right black margin.
The other issue is that the internal floppy drive, which works beautifully and accepts disks and reads them faithfully, is reluctant to let go of disk when we attempt to eject the disk and needs to be prodded with a push pin. That's in the process of being fixed and we're sure that a fully functional drive will be fully repaired in short order. No worries there whatsoever.
However, what we could really use some help with is the analog board. While the analog board is fine and both powers and provides signal to the Mac Plus at the present time, we see that it’s the original analog board and doesn't appear to be in quite a near perfect condition as the logic board. While it is fully functional, we're worried that, perhaps, just perhaps, one or more capacitors may be nearing its end of life and need to be replaced and repaired.
We've provided a bunch of pictures to give you a better idea of what condition it’s currently in.
Would it be too much to ask you folks to take a look and let us know if you see thing(s) wrong with the board that needs repairing before we attempt to sell the re-assembled Mac Plus to some poor, unsuspecting buyer. We always want our customers to be happy and never want them to be sad with any purchase they make from us.
Thank you for taking a look and pointing out anything you observe that may need attention.
Pictures of Analog Board - Different Angles:
https://68kmla.org/bb/index.php?threads/are-there-foreseeable-problems-currently-or-likely-in-the-near-future-with-this-analog-board.48366/

Kinda hard to see anything but thumbnails without signing up. Replacing capacitors is pretty much a given on stuff that old. Finding those first generation keyboards is the real pain.

You can post one or two of those pictures here, if you would please. Also Capacitors are cheap and easy to replace (assuming you have such experience). So anything you CAN replace (assuming you do it correctly and carefully) I would replace. The other thing to consider if it is working fine is that if it ain't broke don't fix it.
